# Почему "Иное дело" наречное выражение?

Tags: наречия

Рассмотрим оборот

```
Иное дело служба. (Достоевский)
Иное дело Гавриил. (Б. Васильев)
Другое дело фельдшер Тумаш. (В. Быков)
Другое дело наш Юра. (Ф. Искандер)
```

В http://www.gramota.tv/spravka/punctum?layout=item&id=58_178
говорят, что **иное дело** это наречное выражение.
Но в наших примерах это очевидно не так по следующим 4-м причинам:

1. Его нельзя заменить наречием (пусть даже без сохранения смысла) или 100% наречным выражением.
2. Оно не отвечает на синтаксический вопрос (как? при каких обстоятельствах? когда? и т.д.).
3. Позиция подлежащего (а у нас явно позиция подлежащего, поскольку можно вставить **это**: **Иное дело - это служба**) не характерна для наречий и наречных выражений вообще. Сравните:
   **Служба - это хорошо**, но **Хорошо - это служба** (???).
4. Похожий фразеологизм **плевое дело** вроде бы не считается наречием. При этом считать его наречием намного больше оснований, чем **иное дело**. Ведь он не может стоять в позиции подлежащего (не рассматриваем искусственные, корявые примеры). Кроме того он отдаленно напоминает наречие **Легко**. Но у нас то совсем другой случай. **Иное дело** является подлежащим и напоминает прилагательное **Иное**, а не наречие **Иной**.

Какие формальные основания послужили тому, чтобы считать **иное дело** в позиции подлежащего - наречным выражением?

ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ:

Ремарка насчет 3-го пункта.
Как выяснилось с подлежащим не все так просто. Я среагировал на конструкцию
`A - это B` автоматически и не задумываясь объявил A - подлежащим. Хотя в реальности подлежащее тут скорее ближе к B, см  [Разбор предложения: подлежащее, сказуемое и это](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/463967)

Тем не менее, разнородность предложений **Иное дело - служба**/**Служба - иное дело** требует какого-то разумного синтаксического объяснения. В отличии от конструкций типа **Плевое дело - служба**/**Служба - плевое дело**, которые легко объясняются банальной расстановкой акцентов.

И, ура, такое объяснение нашлось в справочнике вводных слов (Фармополь).

5-й пункт.

**Естественное дело** - наречное выражение выступающее в функции вводного предложения.

Конечно, это очень интересная вводная конструкция. Хотя бы тем, что я её спутал с подлежащими, а grizzly с именной частью. Но не вдаваясь в исследование этого вводного слова, задам только два мелких вопросика.

1. Почему **иное дело** - наречное выражение? Какой синтаксический вопрос надо задать, как надо извратиться, чтобы этот фразеологизм стал наречием?
2. Можно ли классифицировать конструкцию **естественное дело, что** как вводную? Как вводную + союз? Как наречное выражение + союз?

Comment: *Иное дело - это служба* — "Иное дело" может быть или не быть наречным выражением, но никак не может быть "службой". Вы настолько удивительным образом не понимаете семанжтику и грамматику самых простых высказываний, что я, пожалуй, объясню подробнее: можно сказать или "иное дело — это наречное выражение", или "служба — это иное дело".

Comment: То есть вы отрицаете позицию "иное дело" как подлежащего в подобных фразах? Вы настолько не понимаете смысловую разницу между "Иное дело - служба" и "Служба - иное дело", что прямо удивительно. Придется объяснить подробнее, примерами из нацкорпуса: "Другое дело ― это выскочившая на шее бородавка ..." и "Другое дело ― это прием ...". А вы говорите сказать нельзя...

Comment: Не вижу разницы между "иное дело — служба" и "служба — иное дело". Вы привели цитаты 100-150-летней давности. С Вашего позволения, приведу последнюю цитату полностью: **Другое дело — это прием и хотя некоторое устройство квартиры, прежде чем явиться со всей лавочкой**. Сейчас так действительно не говорят. Но Вы правы, встречается. Вот ещё из нацкорпуса (такого очень много): "скорее ― это фильм...", "быстро ― это пара дней", "раньше — это правильно".

Comment: Ну славно. Вот мы и выявили камень нашего с вами (надеюсь больше ни с кем) преткновения. Разное отношение к паре "иное дело — служба" и "служба — иное дело". И конечно эта фраза не имеет общего с уточняющими, интонационными конструкциями типа "быстро ― это пара дней". "Пара дней - это пара недель" и тд.

Comment: Ок. Но добавлю, что в лучших традициях ведения дискуссии Вы не заметили вот эту цитату: "скорее — это фильм..." и т.п.

Comment: "Скорее - это фильм о чем-то там" = "Скорее всего, это фильм о чем-то там".  Вводное слово. Вы считаете "иное дело" - вводным словом? Или все таки дополнением как во фразе "Служба - иное дело".  Определитесь уже со своей позицией! ;)

Answer (score 3):

1. ***Иное дело*** – сочетание с оценочным значением, близкие синонимы – *иначе, по-другому, совсем не так*. Поэтому его можно назвать **наречным выражением**, во фразеологическом словаре для него дается пометка ***неизм***

[https://phraseologiya.academic.ru/428/иное_дело](https://phraseologiya.academic.ru/428/%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%BE)

Неизм. *Совсем не то, что было; совсем не так, как было*. = Другое дело.

Нелегко одному бороться с трудностями, **иное дело**, когда рядом друзья.
Впечатлительному путешественнику унылыми, голыми казались… северные поселки. **Иное дело** – южные степные деревни, обычно утопающие в зелени садов… (И. Соколов-Микитов.)

2. Синтаксическая роль у этого сочетания бывает разной. Оно может быть **сказуемым** со значением оценки  или **вводным сочетанием**, выражающим отношение к сказанному. Поэтому и оформление тоже разное.

**Сказуемое:**

(1) Служба – (это) **иное дело**.  Тире между подлежащим и сказуемым

(2) **Иное дело** служба. Нет тире при инверсии сказуемого.

(3) **Иное дело** – служба . Тире ставится при инверсии при наличии паузы (авторский вариант)

**Вводное слово**

(4) **Иное дело**, служба. Обособление запятой

(5) **Иное дело** – служба. Обособление с помощью тире.

Оформление вариантов (3) и (5) одинаковое, но толкование может быть различным.

Comment: Сразу же включите в анализ: "Иное дело – это служба" Где тут сказуемое? Каким членом предложения является местоимение "это"? Насчет наречного вопроса: "Иное дело" и "иначе" не заменяют друг друга ни в одном предложении. Сравните: "есть помидоры - это плёвое дело"/"есть помидоры - это плёво". Но "есть помидоры - это иное дело"/"есть помидоры - это иначе" ??? Видимо, придется это списать на кривость синтаксиса с его нелепыми вопросами. И если уж мы говорим о вводных словах, надо проанализировать конструкцию "Иное дело, что он ушел". Есть ли тут вводное или только лишь наречие?

Comment: "Иное дело – это была служба." Здесь все понятно: это - подлежащее, иное дело - вводное слово. Такой же трюк срабатывает и в "Иное дело – это служба.". Но что делать с "Человечище - это был Василий". Тут уже не отделаться вводностью слова. Хотя почему нет? человечище тут тоже занимает позицию вводного.

Comment: Извините, но без комментариев – иногда мне бывает  сложно понять логику мышления другого человека. Я  вполне ясно выразила  свою точку зрения, вы можете принять ее в целом или не принимать вовсе. Я с одинаковым уважением отнесусь к любому вашему выбору :)

Comment: Ок. Надо сказать, что ваш ответ примерно такой же, как у меня на данном этапе осмысления. Но наш ответ я бы ещё не назвал окончательным, процентов на 70% он закрывает вопрос.

Comment: Спасибо за понимание.

Answer (score 1):

Классификация выражения как *наречного* производится по **одной из** его *возможных функций в составе предложения*. У выражения "иное дело" тоже ***не** единственная* возможная функция (другие возможные - *вводное выражение* или *сказуемое*), однако *в вашем вопросе* эта функция рассматривается как *единственная*. Именно поэтому противопоставляемые примеры использования (в которых функция этого выражения иная) оказываются в противоречии с таким пониманием. Если обратиться к словарям, то можно найти многие другие выражения ([*мало сказать, одним словом, в конце концов*](https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/lingvistic/800/%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5) и др.), которые в одних контекстах выступают как наречные, а в других выполняют одну-две отличающихся функции.

**P.S.** Поскольку с наречным выражением примеры менее типичны, предложу один такой:

> Этого фигуранта *справедливо* было бы приговорить к условному сроку,
> иное дело [= *но несправедливо*] казнить.

Comment: Alex_ander, а почему нельзя считать, что ваш пример - это мой пункт (2) Иное дело служба. Нет тире при инверсии сказуемого. Стоит ли выделять  отдельно функцию наречного выражения? Ведь в роли именной части сказуемого стоит именно оно.

Comment: Потому что здесь наречие в функции обстоятельства, а в вашем примере наречие в функции сказуемого. В обоих случаях это наречное выражение.

Comment: Иное дело казнить (= но казнить было бы  несправедливо). Здесь «казнить» – подлежащее, а «иное дело» – наречное выражение в роли сказуемого (но не обстоятельства).

Comment: Я согласен, пример, скажем так, не очень. Но и вы поймите, что, чтобы предъявить адекватный аргумент в пользу наречности, нельзя приводить примеры с выражением в функции сказуемого. Вот если бы мы смогли привести пример с выражением в функции обстоятельства, тогда другое дело. Хотя постойте, вот последнее моё предложение - это ли не тот самый пример классического обстоятельства?

Comment: Тогда (это было бы) другое дело. Неполное предложение, именное сказуемое. Функция обстоятельства? Наречия бывают обстоятельственные и предикативные. Обстоятельственые наречия должны относиться к  какому-либо слову (глаголу обычно). Как вы себе представляете такое сочетание?

Comment: Неполное предложение. Возможно, подлежащее, а не сказуемое. Сравните: Тогда (был бы) конец. Наречные сочетания типа "другое дело" не являются предикативами. См. например rusgram.ru/Предикатив. Там нет ни одного наречного сочетания. И к тому же "другое дело" не употребляться со связкой "стать". Сравните: Это стало хорошо. Но: Это стало другое дело. А допустимость связки "стать" это обязательное условие предикативности. Кроме того, предикатив допускает дательный падеж субъекта. У нас ни о каком субъекте не может быть и речи. Сравните: Мне хорошо. и Мне плевое дело.