# Разбор предложения: подлежащее, сказуемое и это

Tags: синтаксический-разбор, сказуемые, местоимения, подлежащее

Какие подлежащие/сказуемые в предложениях:

> 1. Вася - (вот) это был Человечище.
> 2. Человечище - это был Вася.

В какие члены предложения приткнуть слово "это"?

Comment: https://izamorfix.ru/rus/sint_punkt/tire_podl_skaz.html
"Это, значит" - так называемые указательные частицы

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В состав именного сказуемого входят частицы:  это,  не,  как,  будто,  словно  и др. Например:

Зимний лес будто сказка.
Он не был трусом.